# Errorhandler discord

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make an error handler so my bot will not go offline.

```
async function catchErr (error, message) {
    await client.users.fetch("id").send("ERROR" + error) ("There was an error at channel" + message.channel + "in guild" + message.guild);
    await client.users.get("id").send ("ERROR" + error)
    console.error(error, message);
    await message.author.send(error)
}
```

No error

Comment: But it will not send the error to the user

Comment: it just gos offline

Comment: I tried top.gg and discord.js

Comment: discord servers

Comment: Please update your question with debugging details. It's important to know if you function was even called, and exact line it failed. I recommend using ipdb, if it possible in your case https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb. Also please do not spam at comments section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to make your own. Use the `.catch()` method to catch errors.

Usage:

```
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "ping")) {
        message.channel.send("pong").catch(err => {
            console.log(``)
            console.log(`Unable to Respond in ${message.guild.name}`) | message.channel.send(`**Error.**`).then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
            })
        })
    }
```

*Catches errors when a command is requested...if there is an error.*